# Receive click events from outside dialog

Tags: android

I would like to show a dialog and still be able to receive button click events coming from outside the dialog on the main activity, how can I do that?

In otherwords, if someone clicks on a button outside the dialog and this button is on the main activity screen, then I would like to receive this event.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Would you like that click to be registered (and processed) without dismissing the dialog? I'm not sure that's possible - at least not with the standard dialog framework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a built in feature with Dialogs, however a PopUpWindow does have the ability to receive touches that are outside of the window. You can use PopUpWindow's [setOutsideTouchable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setOutsideTouchable%28boolean%29) and [setTouchIntercepter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setTouchInterceptor%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29) to achieve what you want.